# Kubernetes CSI S3 driver with ReadWriteMany in 2022

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-s3, container-storage-interface

We have on-premises Kubernetes clusters.

Our data is in S3-compatible cloud storage (e.g. Amazon s3).

We want to mount S3 bucket to Kubernetes pods in ReadWriteMany (RWX) mode via a CSI driver.

What non-dead Kuebrnetes CSI RWX S3 drivers exist in 2022?

Answer (score 2):

There is no official AWS support for S3 as a CSI.
There is a fuse driver from Yandex-cloud here:

https://github.com/yandex-cloud/k8s-csi-s3